# Infinite Spawn part deus

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I was here a couple days ago with an issue with a script that was causing an infinite spawn. I fixed that issue but now there is another one. the glitch is back, but in a strange way. It seems to still have issues with the spawn script. Currently it spawns a single wave of enemies, waits 5 seconds, then spawns another set, and declares "wave 3". It should spawn one wave, declare "wave 1", wait for them to be killed, then spawn two waves and declare "wave 2"

I used some debug logs to try to get it. here is the result:
0spawn
1
1spawn
2
2spawn
3
3spawn
3message
1
2
3
4
5
6

Spawn script

```
static var waveNumberMessage : boolean = false;

function Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("CoStart");
}

function CoStart() : IEnumerator
{
    while (true)
        yield CoUpdate();
}


function CoUpdate(){

if (deathcounter.timeToSpawn == true){

    if (spawnCount == 0 && deathcounter.timeToSpawn == true){
    spawnCount = deathcounter.enemySpawnCount;
    }


        while(spawnCount >= 0)
        {
            var target= Instantiate(targetPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

            target.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.right * (150 + waveCounter * 10));    

            spawnCount = spawnCount - 1;
            Debug.Log(waveCounter + "spawn");
            yield WaitForSeconds (5);

            if (spawnCount == 0){

                waveCounter = waveCounter + 1;
                Debug.Log(waveCounter);
                deathcounter.timeToSpawn = false;
                waveNumberMessage = true;

            }

        }




}

}


function OnGUI()
{
if(waveNumberMessage == true)
    {
        GUI.Box(Rect((Screen.width/2 - 100),(Screen.height/2 - 40),200,80),"Wave: " + waveCounter);
            Invoke("HideNumberMessage", 3.0f);
                        Debug.Log(waveCounter + "message");
    }
   }

function HideNumberMessage()
{
    waveNumberMessage = false;
}
```

death counter script

```
static var enemyDeathCount = 0;
static var enemySpawnCount = 1;
static var timeToSpawn : boolean = true;

function Update () {

    if(enemyDeathCount % 3 == 0 && enemyDeathCount != 0){
        timeToSpawn = true;
        enemySpawnCount = enemySpawnCount + 1;


    }


}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It would improve your chances of getting an answer if you could properly format your code. (MonoDevelop has an auto-format feature) As far as I can tell (I only know C#) the 'yield WaitForSeconds (5);' doesn't seem right as it isn't returning anything, so its probably not waiting for 5 seconds but being ignored.

Comment: No, it is. That is the proper format for a wait command. That part works just fine.

Comment: Then please explain what exactly is wrong and most importantly what you expect to happen instead. You posted the series of logs but its hard to make out which logs in the code they refer to.

Comment: I explained it a bit better what's going on.